# Merge PDF files from post custom fields(ACF) into one PDF file and respond back the created PDF file, Wordpress(AJAX Request)

Tags: ajax, advanced-custom-fields, pdf

I am using Advanced Custom Fields plugin(free version) for attaching 3 different pdf files to a single post.

After displaying a list of posts on a template, with a button click I am making an AJAX Request to get the files of all displayed posts.

Since every post has 3 PDF files, I want to merge all these files of all posts to a single PDF file and download that single file.

What I did so far :

AJAX Request on button click:

```
function merklisteDownload() {
    window.event.preventDefault()
    var m = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('merkliste_items')) || []
    var ids = []
    if (m.length > 0) {
        m.forEach(element => {
            ids.push(element.id)
        });
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            action: 'get_post_files',
            ids: ids
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response.data)
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    });
}
```

And admin-ajax.php code:

```
    function get_post_files(){
    $data = [];
    foreach ($_POST['ids'] as $post_id) {
        array_push($data, [
            'id'                        => $post_id,
            'title'                     => get_the_title($post_id),
            'category'                  => get_the_category($post_id)[0]->name,
            'front_image'               => get_field('front_image', $post_id)['sizes']['large'] == true ? get_field('front_image', $post_id)['sizes']['large'] : null,
            'back_image'                => get_field('back_image', $post_id)['sizes']['large'] == true ? get_field('back_image', $post_id)['sizes']['large'] : null,
            'technische_daten'          => get_field('technische_daten', $post_id)['url'], //file
            'lichttechnische_parameter' => get_field('lichttechnische_parameter', $post_id)['url'], //file
            'reach_zertifikat'          => get_field('reach-zertifikat', $post_id)['url'],  //file
        ]);
    }
    wp_send_json_success($data);
    wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_get_post_files', 'get_post_files');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_post_files', 'get_post_files');
```

Everything is working till now, I am able to get the file URLs of each post, but I dont know how to merge these files into one and return the file as AJAX Response, then download that file.

Any help?

Best regards.

Comment: how are post IDs mapped to PDF files? I don't understand the non-english field names so apologies if one of them is a PDF url of some sort. You would need to load the PDF into a variable, then merge them somehow. How you would do the actual merging isn't a WordPress question but a generic PHP question better asked on stackoverflow.  Also is there a specific reason you used the old admin ajax API for AJAX instead of a modern REST API endpoint?

Comment: @TomJNowell, the three last fields inside $data array are links to pdf files('technische_daten', 'lichttechnische_parameter', 'reach_zertifikat' ). I used the old way for no reason(my first founded solution to achieve the functionality). Do you have any idea how to do the merge in admin-ajax.php? Can I use fpdf because I've seen that this package can do the merge of pdfs, but I don't know how to integrate properly a php package on wordpress.

Comment: if you know how to use fpdf then sure, just include it in your plugin then require and use it in the place you plan to use it